# Book or story about scientists repeatedly teleporting copies of a human to a hostile alien planet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, books, aliens, teleportation

The plot:

- A guy comes to an underground facility for experiments or something.
- Scientists put him in a small dark room for a small amount of time and let him out without any change.
- The procedure repeats and after pressuring the scientists, they reveal to him that his copy is teleported to another planet.
- The goal was to reach a beacon or a device which will allow the teleporter to work both ways or something.
- It turns out the planet is rich in metals, but the alien life there is much stronger and tears the copied guy apart very quickly, so they try more times with newer copies and make some progress.

I don't know how it turns out. That's why I want to read it to the end, but don't know the name or author. Please help.

Comment: Some overlap with "Rogue Moon", but that has no exploitable alien planet and the character is fully aware of the duplicate's feelings.

Comment: Do we ever see the other planet from the point of view of the test subject?

Comment: the original guy and the scientist have the means to monitor the other planet and what happens to the copies, but i am not sure about the copies point of view
i guess at some point yes

Comment: Also some overlap with Pohl's *Farthest Star*, but there the original was aware from the start that he was being copied.

Comment: Was this the only transporter or did it mention that there were many more and that they were identical copies of themselves throughout the galaxy?

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it might be the unproduced film script *Shadow 19*, by screenwriter Jon Spaihts.

The protagonist, Captain Conrad Vance of the Offworld Marine Corps, is ordered to serve as the subject of a research project, located deep underground, which is run by the "Science Agency" and kept secret even from the government:

> **ELEVATOR:** [...] Lights flash to life, and the elevator descends.
>
> The floor indicator reaches the lowest basement level - but the elevator KEEPS SINKING.
>
> [...]
>
> **SECRETARY DAIN:** The Department of Defense relies on the State Science Agency for key technologies. When they requested a Marine for special duty, I couldn’t easily say no. I’m beginning to regret that decision. I want to know what this project's about.
>
> **VANCE:** I signed a writ of secrecy, sir. I can't say much.

Vance is informed that his new, top-secret mission is to travel to the planet Erix by means of the instantaneous "Lang Transporter", make a hazardous multi-day trek from the transporter to an an unmanned crawler, and repair it. The crawler is supposed to be taking part in an autonomous terraforming operation, but has been damaged by the unexpectedly ferocious native lifeforms, which have evolved to take advantage of the planet's high metal content:

> **ADA:** Erix is richer in heavy elements than Earth. Tungsten, chromium, titanium. Living things on Erix incorporate those metals.

From Vance's point of view, the teleportation process initially appears to fail:

> The transport chamber’s door opens. Vance steps out onto the catwalk. He’s untouched, his armor unmarked.
>
> **VANCE:** I’m still here.
>
> **DIRECTOR MARBECK (O.S.):** Technical difficulties, Captain.
>
> [...]
>
> **VANCE:** Technical difficulties. But this is safe.
>
> **DIRECTOR MARBECK:** Perfectly safe in theory. It takes a week to recharge the transporter. One week. Until then - continue training.

but unbeknownst to him, a "shadow" duplicate of him was successfully sent to Erix, and then promptly killed by alien wildlife.

After a few more "failed" teleportation attempts, he starts getting suspicious and presses the scientists for an explanation, and the scientists reluctantly explain the true nature of the teleportation process. From that point on, Vance involves himself in the planning of subsequent iterations, using increasingly powerful armor and weapons. Eventually:

> his 19th "shadow" is successful in reaching and repairing the crawler. However, both the original Vance and Shadow Nineteen find evidence that the terraforming project is in the process of exterminating a native race of sentient beings, which the Science Agency knew about and covered up.

> Shadow Nineteen sabotages the project, rides the crawler back to the transporter, and hotwires it to teleport himself back to Earth. The resulting *duplicate* of Shadow Nineteen teams up with the original Vance, and they (plus Vance's romantic interest, a rebel scientist) have to fight their way out of the research station, in order to reveal the truth about what the project has been up to.

Comment: I haven't linked to the script since I'm not sure if it's being distributed with the author's permission, but it's easily findable with a Google search.